# SSH Connection Silently Dies

Tags: ssh

As the title says I'm having a very strange problem with SSH connections at my house, it seems that after about 3-5 minutes of inactivity any SSH sessions I have open will just shutdown and leave the SSH connection in an appeared active state as I do not receive a timeout or reset message and     I cannot provide any input or receive any output, it's as if it has become frozen in time and I must close the terminal window itself.

I know that the server's I am connecting too are not the problem as I regularly use them at the office with no issues, sometimes keeping a session open for hours on end.

I have attempted to set the SSH KeepAlive with no success, running `top` has been the only solution I can find so far to keep the connection open and it does not always guarantee.

I have been attempting to debug this issue for quite some time and have come up with absolutely nothing and beginning to wonder if this could possibly be my ISP ( Brighthouse ) or my modem/router ( RCA Thompson DWG855T ) causing the problem, I am leaning towards the later but I cannot remove and test the connection alone as the RCA is a router/modem combo .....

As anyone experienced this problem before and found a viable solution?

Here is the -vvv ssh with certain info #### out

```
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data ###
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ##### port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ### type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file ###.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file #### type 1
debug1: identity file #### type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 116/256
debug2: bits set: 488/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename ####
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 17
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename ####
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 16
debug1: Host '####' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in ####:17
debug2: bits set: 486/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: #### (0x0)
debug2: key: #### (0x407f00)
debug2: key: #### (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: ####.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: ####.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: ####.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 32:97:a1:c0:1a:26:24:e2:a2:c2:be:47:46:31:a9:94
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: tty_make_modes: ospeed 38400
debug3: tty_make_modes: ispeed 38400
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: Can you post ssh -vvv output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the timeout settings on the router at the server side (the system you're connecting to). I usually run into the 5-minute delay as a result of the default settings on Sonicwall firewalls. In these cases, I'll make the following changes on the ssh server *IF* I don't have access to correct this on the firewall side.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I add or make sure the following directives are set:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
KeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

Restart the ssh daemon, and the issue should go away.

You can also make the change on your client system. This entails adding `ServerAliveInterval 60` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and reconnecting or adding `-o ServerAliveInterval=60` to your ssh connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the response but as stated I can connect to servers at the office for hours on end without disconnection this also is not a single server itself it is all ssh connections.

Comment: I understand. If the problem is an issue from home, then one of the following needs to be changed: the keepalives that I posted can reduce the impact of a short timeout on your organization's firewall if you can't have the firewall settings modified.

Comment: Added the configuration settings and issue persists

Comment: Did you restart the daemon on the server you were connecting to following the configuration change? Also, what are you connecting FROM? Windows? Linux? Using PuTTY?

Comment: Yes the server was restarted I am connecting from OSX.

Comment: If you want to test quickly, you can make the change on your client system. In Linux, this entails adding `ServerAliveInterval 60` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and reconnecting. On the Mac, you will need to use sudo/root to add the same parameter to `/private/etc/ssh_config` or add `-o ServerAliveInterval 60` to your ssh string.

Comment: Finally seems adding ServerAliveInterval to the /private/etc/ssh_config fixed the problem, is their a reason why adding it to my private ssh config ~/.ssh/config did not provide the same results as this was previously attempted

Comment: Does SSH expect to read the ServerAliveInterval variable from the user prefs file?  

Also, I have a problem at work where the router supplied by the ISP insists on dropping SSH connections; it sounds like the inverse of your problem and your home router can't keep the session open (or your ISP has poor routing or forcibly drops the almost-inactive session!). I work around dropped sessions by starting one up then leaving `top` or `watch --interval=0.1 iostat -m` open when not in use; it's constantly pumping a low amount of data and this keeps the TCP session alive.

Comment: `KeepAlive` is not mentioned in `man 5 sshd_config`

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar problems with while connecting over bad connections. The following configuration did the trick for me. In the server's sshd_config add the following

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

For details you can lookup manual page of sshd_config. Good luck : )